# Firestore: Reading multiple documents in transaction

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I run the Firestore transaction it gives me the error :

> "Every document read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction."

But all the documents that I am trying to read in the transaction are also being written to in the code below ?

```
    db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
    let doc1: DocumentSnapshot
    let doc2: DocumentSnapshot
    let doc3: DocumentSnapshot

    do {
        try doc1 = transaction.getDocument(self.doc1Ref)
        try doc2 = transaction.getDocument(self.doc2Ref)
        try doc3 = transaction.getDocument(self.doc3Ref)
    } catch let fetchError as NSError {
        errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
        return nil
    }



    // WRITES TO DOC1, DOC2, DOC3
    guard let userPostCount = doc1.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
        let locationPostCount = doc2.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
        let itemPostCount = doc3.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
        let locationAvgRating = doc2.data()?["averageRating"] as? Float,
        let itemAvgRating = doc3.data()?["averageRating"] as? Float else { return nil }


    // Create post on another document not in transaction
    transaction.setData(post.dictionary, forDocument: self.doc4Ref)


    // Update counts for #userPosts, #locationPosts, #itemPosts, avgLocationRating, avgItemRating
    transaction.updateData(["postCount": userPostCount + 1], forDocument: self.doc1Ref)

    let newAvgLocationRating = ((avgLocationRating * Float(locationPostCount)) + Float(post.rating)) / (Float(locationPostCount) + 1.0)
    transaction.updateData(["postCount": locationPostCount + 1, "averageRating": newAvgLocationRating], forDocument: self.doc2Ref)

    let newAvgItemRating = ((avgItemRating * Float(itemPostCount)) + Float(post.rating)) / (Float(itemPostCount) + 1.0)
    transaction.updateData(["postCount": locationPostCount + 1, "averageRating": newAvgItemRating], forDocument: self.doc3Ref)


    // Add postID to user and location
    transaction.setData(["postID": self.postRef.documentID, "locationID": post.locationID, "itemID": post.itemID, "rating": post.rating, "timestamp": post.timestamp], forDocument: self.doc1Ref.collection("posts").document(self.postRef.documentID))

    transaction.setData(["postID": self.postRef.documentID, "rating": post.rating, "timestamp": post.timestamp], forDocument: self.doc3Ref.collection("posts").document(self.postRef.documentID))


    return nil
}) { (object, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print("done")
    }
}
```

Is it just not possible to do multiple .getDocument(*documentReference*) in a transaction?

Is there another way to accomplish this issue?

Comment: Any reason why you're not showing the writes?  Makes it kinda hard to see if you might be doing something wrong.  Also we can't see how you're assigning the three refs.

Comment: Just added the writes @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1):

you should put all your `if` operations in `do` and `else` operations in `catch`

don't use them outside the block.

thats what the error is saying `"Every document read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction."`.
for ex. your code

```
// WRITES TO DOC1, DOC2, DOC3
guard let userPostCount = doc1.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
    let locationPostCount = doc2.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
    let itemPostCount = doc3.data()?["postCount"] as? Int,
    let locationAvgRating = doc2.data()?["averageRating"] as? Float,
    let itemAvgRating = doc3.data()?["averageRating"] as? Float else { return nil }
```

is doing operations with `doc1`,`doc2` outside the scope of do catch block

Answer (score 0):

*I just noticed you are using Apple's swift scripting. My answer is standards based JavaScript but I hope it helps you. I don't use or know anything about Swift...*

As far as reading data from 3 documents simultaneously, the way to do this is using javascript's `.promise.all`.  While the below code is not precisely your solution, you can get the just of how to do it.

You basically push each `.get` into an array then you `.promise.all` that array `.then` you iterate over the returned data.

```
        try {
            targetRef.get().then(function(snap) {
                if (snap.exists) {
                    for (var key in snap.data()) {
                        if (snap.data().hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            fetchPromise = itemRef.doc(key).get();
                            fetchArray.push(fetchPromise);
                        }
                    }
                    Promise.all(fetchArray).then(function(values) {
                        populateSelectFromQueryValues(values,"order-panel-one-item-select");
                        if(!selectIsEmpty("order-panel-one-item-select")){
                            enableSelect("order-panel-one-item-select");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                toast("error check console");
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
        }
```

Comment: I need to read data from all 3 documents and I don't think that you can read and write data in a batch